# How to change row number in a FOR loop... (MATLAB newbie)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, row

I have a set of data that is <106x25 double> but this is inside a struct and I want to extract  the data into a matrix. I figured a simple FOR loop would accomplish this but I have hit a road block quite quickly in my MATLAB knowledge.

This is the only piece of code I have, but I just don't know enough about MATLAB to get this simple bit of code working:

```
>> x = zeros(106,25); for i = 1:106, x(i,:) = [s(i).surveydata]; end
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

`'s'` is a very very large file (in excess of 800MB), it is a `<1 x 106 struct>`. Suffice it to say, I just need to access a small portion of this which is `s.surveydata` where most rows are a <1 x 25 double> (a row vector IIRC) and some of them are empty and solely return a `[]`.

`s.surveydata` obviously returns the results for all of the `surveydata` contained where `s(106).surveydata` would return the result for the last row. I therefore need to grab `s(1:106).surveydata` and put it into a matrix `x`. Is creating the matrix first by using `x = zeros(106,25)` incorrect in this situation?

Cheers and thanks for your time!

*Ryan*

Comment: What is the -1 for? +1 to compensate. BTW: Do not forget to accept an answer if it was helpful.

Comment: To anyone coming here with the `??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` error - The simple problem is that your data you're inserting doesn't match the size of your vertex / matrix. In my case 12 of the 106 rows were `[]` blank and that was giving me the error.

Comment: The answer from superbest has an if statement that should show you how to fix your `??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, cleanest, and fastest way to write all the survey data into an array is to directly catenate it, using [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html):

```
x = cat(1,s.surveydata);
```

EDIT: note that if any surveydata is empty, `x` will have fewer rows than `s` has elements. If you need `x` to have the same amount of rows as `s` has elements, you can do the following:

```
%# find which entries in s have data
%# note that for the x above, hasData(k) contains the 
%# element number in s that the k-th row of x came from
hasData = find(arrayfun(@(x)~isempty(x.surveydata),s));

%# initialize x to NaN, so as to not confuse the
%# real data with missing data entries. The call
%# to hasData when indexing makes this robust to an 
%# empty first entry in s
x = NaN(length(s),length(s(hasData(1)).surveydata);

%# fill in only the rows of x that contain data
x(hasData,:) = cat(1,s(hasData).surveydata);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Great answer, I knew MATLAB would have a function capable of doing this I just figured using a loop would of been easier than finding out what a function that does this is called.

Again, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

No, creating an array of zeroes is not incorrect. In fact it's a good idea. You don't have to declare variables in Matlab before using them, but for loops, pre-allocating has speed benefits.

```
x = zeros(size(s), size(s(1)));

for i = 1:106
    if ~isempty(s(i).surveydata)
        x(i, :) = s(i).surveydata;
    end
end
```

Should accomplish what you want.

EDIT: Since OP indicated that some rows are empty, I accounted for that like he said.

Comment: Ahh, I just went through my data and not EVERY row is a `<1 x 25>` some are purely [] empty. Could this be the reason I am getting the `??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` error?

Comment: @Accendi Absolutely. Look at the value of variable `i` in the workspace: It should be the first index where `surveydata` is empty. Or simply type `s(i).surveydata` to see whether it is `[]` and `s(i).surveydata` to see that it is not `[]` (unless `i` is 1). To fix the problem, you can do the assignment only `if ~isempty(s(i).surveydata)` (however, if actual data can be 0, you may want to initialize `x` to something else, e.g. `NaN(106,25)`).

Comment: Yeah it was from checking individually that i noticed the blank entries and I needed that `~isempty` thanks!

Comment: Could some please post this as an answer as it worked 100% (I can't as I have less than 100 rep):



Here is the solution I came to thanks to a combination of everyone who posted, so thanks. I thought giving the solution would be good for anyone else who finds the error:`??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

    x = zeros(106,25);
    for i = 1:106
      if ~isempty(s(i).surveydata)
        x(i, :) = s(i).surveydata;
      end
    end

Comment: @Accendi: One can always edit one's own answer after it was posted, as Superbest just did. Anyway, when I wrote the above comment (where when I wrote `s(i).surveydata` the second time, I meant `s(i-1).surveydata`, ahem), I was rather sure there would be a way without a loop, but it would take me too long to figure it out (not too experienced with `arrayfun` yet).

Answer (score 0):

what about this?
what `s` is?

if `s(i).surveydata` is scalar:

```
x = zeros(106,25); 
for i = 1:106
x(i,1) = [s(i).surveydata]; 
end
```

I am guessing that is what you want tough it is not clear at all :

if `s(i).surveydata` is row vector:

```
x = zeros(106,25); 
for i = 1:106
x(i,:) = [s(i).surveydata]; 
end
```

if `s(i).surveydata` is column  vector:

```
x = zeros(106,25); 
for i = 1:106
x(i,:) = [s(i).surveydata]'; 
end
```

Comment: you need the second or third codes i think, Don't know what you want... it it works cooll if not put all the code in the question.

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying, sorry I can't properly communicate my problem but can I check what "what s is?" means?

Also, it is a row vector <1 x 25>.

Comment: Oh I can tell you that, s is a Struct which is 888,000,000 bytes in size BUT s.surveydata is one of the pieces in there and I want to extract this. It contains 106 separate people's responses (hence the 1:106) and each row of responses has 25 columns.

e.g. `s(106).surveydata` returns:
`ans =

     3     1     4     3     3     2     1     3     4     1     2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     3   NaN     2     2     2   NaN     2     2     3   NaN`

Comment: I just want to iterate through this from s(1:106).surveydata and insert the resulting answer into a matrix.

Comment: put all the code in the question and reedit it, please. someone will know what to do, put as many details as you can please